# IdP Vs Authoritative Source Vs SAML Vs SSO in IAM

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, identity-management

Could someone please help me to understand the difference among the following entities in IAM with real word examples.

1. IdP
2. Authoritative Source
3. SSO
4. SAML
5. OAuth

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `IdP` is an `Authoritative Source` of identities for an organisation. An entity outwith the organisation can allow identities provided by the `IdP` to login to its resources, for example ebooks. The `IdP` can choose to use `SSO`, which means the identities (i.e. the users) only need to provide their credentials once (username/password for example) for as long as an `SSO` session lasts, for example 24 hours.

In order for an external resource provider such as an ebook provider to request that identities (i.e. users) be identified at login, it can ask the `IdP` to release information about those identities using either `SAML` or `OAuth2`.

The `IdP` and external resource provider can have `SSO` independent of each other. A typical flow might be:

1. User goes to https://someebooks.com
2. someebooks.com sends the user to their `IdP` along with SAML requesting the user be authenticated by the `IdP`.
3. The `IdP` authenticates the user and sets up an `SSO` session for them
4. The `IdP` sends the user back to someebooks.com with some `SAML` containing information about the user.
5. someebooks.com allows the user to access the ebooks and sets up its own `SSO` session for the user.
6. if the someebooks.com `SSO` session finishes, go back to step 2.
7. the user decides to go to https://morebooks.com which sends them to their `IdP`. As they already have an `IdP` `SSO` session from step 3, they don't need to login again.
8. The `IdP` sends the user to morebooks.com with information about them in `SAML`.

The flow is similar for `OAuth2`. It uses different tokens from `SAML`. Both are a way of requesting that an identity (user) be authenticated by its `Authoritative Source` and that the `Authoritative Source` release information about the user.

`OAuth2` uses a token released by the `IdP` to allow, for example, someebooks.com to directly request information about the user from the `IdP`. It's more complex than `SAML`.

Information about the user might be a course enrolment. e.g. they are studying a medical degree. An ebook provider may only be prepared to allow access to its ebooks to medical students. The information in the `SAML` or `OAuth2` response from the `IdP` (step 4) may include this information, if they are studying for a medical degree. The `IdP` knows this as it is the `Authoritative Source` for the user.

In summary, the `IdP` AUTHENTICATES the user and the result is sent to the resource provider which AUTHORIZES the user based on information about the user the `IdP` sends to it (`SAML`) or based on information is asks the `IdP` to release about the user (`OAuth2`).

Comment: This is a great explanation!, thnaks very much for your time.